# Ejecutar Método Cada Cierto Tiempo En C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual tengo un método con este código:

```
private void RecibosPercepciones()
    {            
        CultureInfo ci2 = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        String dia = ci2.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).ToString();
        if (dia == "lunes")
        {
            IEnumerable<Registro_Percepciones2> RP = new Registro_Percepciones2().GetAll();

            foreach(var item in RP)
            {
                if (item.Pagos_Realizados != item.No_Pagos)
                {
                    new Detalle_RPercerciones()
                    {
                        Folio = folp,
                        id_RPercepciones = item.idRegistroP,
                        Monto = item.Monto / item.No_Pagos
                    }.Insert();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

en este código obtengo el día de la semana, y si es igual al que yo quiero se ejecuta la función, pero todavía me queda un problema.
El problema es que si cierro y abro la aplicación otra vez, el código se vuelve a ejecutar, y no quiero eso, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que este código se ejecute solo una vez, aunque la aplicación se cierre y se abra, es decir, por ejemplo si abro la aplicación la primera vez se ejecuta el código, pero si lo cierro y lo abro otra vez que ya no se ejecute.

Comment: Un método que uso a menudo es la creación de un bloc de notas en la carpeta raiz donde guardo este tipo de información con un carácter, supongamos que necesito que una función se ejecute solo una vez, o se guarde alguna configuración para los próximos inicios de sesión. Lo que hago es: en un bloc de notas escribir un carácter (o una cadena de caracteres) que dependiendo el valor que tengan es lo que va a ocurrir, de lo contrario la función se ejecutara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo pensaría hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
private void RecibosPercepciones()
{            
   if(EjecutarHoy())
   {
    CultureInfo ci2 = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    String dia = ci2.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).ToString();
    if (dia == "lunes")
    {
        IEnumerable<Registro_Percepciones2> RP = new 
        Registro_Percepciones2().GetAll();

        foreach(var item in RP)
        {
            if (item.Pagos_Realizados != item.No_Pagos)
            {
                new Detalle_RPercerciones()
                {
                    Folio = folp,
                    id_RPercepciones = item.idRegistroP,
                    Monto = item.Monto / item.No_Pagos
                }.Insert();
            }
        }
     //Se ejecuto una vez
     TareaRealizada();
     }
   }
}

private bool EjecutarHoy()
{
//Aquí tu código para preguntar (en un archivo de texto, una Base de datos, etc)
// si existe el registro/bandera devolver false para no ejecutar otra vez.
}

private void TareaRealizada()
{
//Aquí tu código para escribir (en un archivo de texto, una Base de datos, etc) 
// que tu metodo se ejecuto. 
}
```

Despues que has pasado por el foreach llamaría a un metodo **TareaRealizada()** que escriba en un fichero de texto, que inserte un log en una Base de datos o lo que tu decidas pero debes persistir la información que indique que ya has ejecutado la tarea el día de hoy.

Para no ejecutar la tarea nuevamente, crearía un metodo **EjecutarHoy()** que busque ese registro y si ya existe devolver un bool para indicar si vas a ejecutar o no la tarea.